# Remove arrow from disabled QComboBox while respecting style

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

In the picture below, the first `QComboBox` is disabled:

[image]

I want to emphasize the fact that the value cannot be changed by removing the arrow of disabled `QComboBox`es.

I've tried modifying the stylesheet already being used to:

```
QComboBox::down-arrow:disabled {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  image: none;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

But it doesn't solve the issue and conflicts with my current style (set using `qApp->setStyle("fusion")`):

[image]

How can I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick can be done by using a [`QProxyStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) and returning a null `QRect` for the arrow subcontrol ([`QProxyStyle::subControlRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#subControlRect)). A `QProxyStyle` allows you to vary specific behaviours of a style without the need of implementing a whole new one (it wraps the original style).

```
class MyProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle {
public:
  MyProxyStyle(const QString& base_style_name) : QProxyStyle(base_style_name) {}

  QRect MyProxyStyle::subControlRect(QStyle::ComplexControl cc,
                                     const QStyleOptionComplex* option,
                                     QStyle::SubControl sc,
                                     const QWidget* widget) const override
  {
    if (cc == CC_ComboBox && sc == SC_ComboBoxArrow && !widget->isEnabled()) return QRect();
    return QProxyStyle::subControlRect(cc, option, sc, widget);
  }
};

// ...

qApp->setStyle(new MyProxyStyle("fusion"));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could write this in Python?

Comment: @somethingvague this post is focused on C++ but you can implement it quite straightforward in Python following https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QProxyStyle.html. Regarding the other parameters, the combo-box arrow sub-control in Python is `QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_ComboBoxArrow` for example. Hope it can help; if not, please feel free to open a new question (you can link to this one as reference if it helps you)

Comment: This solution leaves an empty space at the location of the arrow. Do you know how to get rid of it?